# How to Bluetooth remote control buttons?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, remote-control

I paired an Amazon Echo Bluetooth remote with my PC and it works, but I'd like to reassign the buttons to send different keystrokes. Is there an app to do that? Or by hacking the registry?

Comment: If you can find out what keypress is sent by the device then you might be able to use AutoHotkey to send a different hotkey.  https://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: AutoHotKey would remap my keyboard keys too since the remote is sending arrow keys and Enter.